# PHP/SQL:: variable indexing in SQL statement

Tags: php, indexing, string-interpolation

I put this in an SQL statement:

```
WHERE course_num = '$course_details['course_num']'
      term_cd = '$course_details['term_cd']'
      term_year = '$course_details['term_year']'
      course_title = '$course_details['course_title']'
      units = '$course_details['units']'
```

and got an error. Because this clearly doesn't work, how do you index a variable in an SQL statement?

Comment: You're also missing lots of `AND` connectors between the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use
    {$arrayvar['index']}

You can also omit the single quotes, but I think it's better to have them.